# Autofit row height for specific range , then resize entire row height for each row ,as height of each cell after autofit on the cited range?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to Autofit row height only for specific range e.g ("B3:B8") `But not autofit the entire row`.
Autofit row height for specific range , then resize entire row height for each row ,depends on height of each cell after autofit on the cited range respectively.
On the below code , I did not use `EntireRow` but the code forcibly autofit entire row.
In advance, thanks for your help.

```
Sub AutoFit_Range()
 
    Dim rng As Range
     Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("B3:B8")
         rng.Rows.AutoFit
 
End Sub
```

Comment: It will resize the entire row but it will use the height based on your range. It’s not possible to resize only the cells in your row range, meaning having the rest of the row at a different height … or have I misunderstood you?

Comment: @Skin I need to set height of `entire row` based on autofitted of my specific range `("B3:B8")`

Comment: It looks like it doesn't do it just for the selected range.  Someone may have a solution though.

Comment: As stated in a before comment, the `RowHeight` property can be set/AutoFit only for `EntireRow`. So Excel makes a guess regarding your wish and `AutoFit` the entire row, even if you used `Row`. Its guess in such a case is easy to be done, because there is no other alternative. Looking to your answer in a comment, I am not sure I understood which is what you really want, or what you  cannot understand based on a specific logic/belief. Did my comment clarify the issue?

Comment: I must confess I do not know what is to be answered. Even if your question is so "clear", I cannot understand it... You do not need to set the entire row height, because this is what Excel does, even if you wouldn't do that.

Comment: Since I cannot understand the question, I cannot understand the answer, neither. Why don't you mark it as accepted answer if it did what you want? Even if I cannot understand what you want...

Comment: @FaneDure , Assuming on my sheet, I only have values on range(“B3:B10), I need to autofit row height for that range , then resize entire row height for each row ,depends on height of each cell after autofit on the cited range respectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### AutoFit (Entire) Rows of a Range

- It will copy the range (including its column widths) to another worksheet, autofit the rows there and loop through the rows of the new range and use their heights to be set in the initial range.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub AutoFit_Range()
    
    Const rgAddress As String = "B3:B8"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim ash As Object: Set ash = ActiveSheet
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(1)
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dws.Range(rgAddress)
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = drg.Rows.Count
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet
    Set sws = wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count))
    
    drg.Copy
    
    Dim srg As Range
    With sws.Range("A1")
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
        Set srg = .Resize(rCount)
    End With
    srg.EntireRow.AutoFit
    
    Dim r As Long
    For r = 1 To rCount
        drg.Rows(r).RowHeight = srg.Rows(r).RowHeight
    Next r
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    sws.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    ash.Activate
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: This a good idea (as no direct method on vba) , Please, instead of copy data to a new sheet and make calculations, ** is it possible** to do all that on memory, meaning `using arrays

Comment: Please, try explaining what difference is between processing the range in this way and the initial code row `rng.Rows.AutoFit`. Please, also  note that I do not want saying that it is not any difference. I would only like to understand **what should be different**... I could not understand the question and maybe I will better understand it  if you try clarifying the issue I am asking about...

Comment: @user22: Of course not, you're dealing with the font sizes, row heights, and whatnot, all of which have nothing to do with arrays.

Comment: @FaneDuru: Imagine `C3` has a font of size `24` but OP wants to autofit for a font of `16` in `B3`. Or there are multiple rows in `D3`...

Comment: Aha... I could not imagine that he wants the other columns not showing all their content. But everybody may want something peculiar... Now, I can understand the question. :)

Comment: Voted it up,  especially for the imagination in understanding the question...

Comment: @FaneDuru there is another piece of code will set row height to equal to 45 or size of cell after Autofit (`bigger size will be used`) .I think no need to cite that on my question.

Comment: @user22 So, what? Do you suggest that I could understand what you want if somebody fixed the `RowHeight` to a specific value? **You should explain that there are bigger fonts in the following columns, as @VBasic2008 did**, in order to have a clear question. Of course, on my taste and my level of English. I could simple not imagine that you want to have columns not showing all their content.

Answer (score 1):

Here something.

```
Sub fitheightfromacell()

Range("B3:B8").Select
Selection.RowHeight = Range("B3").Height
Range("B3").Select
End Sub
```

if want put specific height to b3:b8

you can do that too

```
Sub heightresize()

Range("B3:B8").Select
Selection.RowHeight = 30
Range("B3").Select
End Sub
```

the 30 is the height you want manually.
if you want to take height from another cell, just uses the first code,

or autofit just selected rows

```
Sub autofitslectionrows()

Range("B3:B8").Select
Selection.Rows.AutoFit
Range("B3").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: this will `Autofit Column B`,meaning **resize column width**, this not required on my question

Comment: try this
Sub PAUNOCU()

    Range("B:B").Select
    Selection.RowHeight = Range("B3").Height
Range("B3").Select
End Sub
Try this.
will get rowheight from b3 to all b rows.
Don´t need to dowvote my anwser, just let me know that i misunderstanding your question, was sufficient, i am just try to help.
Maybe you can go from there.

Comment: I tried your `Sub PAUNOCU()` , But it just set row height for **entire column B** to equal height of cell `B`.and sorry for downvote , I will fix.

Comment: just change the range then.
Range("B3:B8").Select 
i edited my anwser.

Comment: update my anwser, if i get you right.

Comment: i think the third solution of my anwser is what you need.

Comment: I am afraid, but your `third solution` is the same as my code on question.